# Does Paypal's subscr_payment get called if there is a 14 day trial for the first signup and payment of 0?

Tags: paypal

Does subscr_payment get called if there is a 14 day trial for the first signup and payment of 0? I just want to make sure I only get the notification when there is a payment greater than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no payment is made, then the subscr_payment IPN would not be triggered.  You would get a subsc_signup IPN at the time the subscription is created, but you wouldn't get subscr_payment until an actual payment takes place.

Comment: Do you mean 'would *not* be triggered'?